# Javascript "getElementsByClassName" not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a website with a picture of a tree, I have then used Ajax to remove that tree and insert a number using javascript. What I used for that was;

```
document.getElementById("cut_oak_tree");
```

I have now added another tree on the page, which should have the exact same function as the first tree, except that only the tree that you clicked on, shall be removed. To avoid duplicating code, I have tried adding following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cut_oak_tree");
```

and then changed my div from using `id` to `class`. However, nothing happens when I click any of the trees now. My current ajax code right now, looks like this:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            var getClass = document.getElementsByClassName("cut_oak_tree").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;//ask for this.
            for(i=0;i<getClass.length;i++)
            {
                getClass[i].innerHTML = "";
            }
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","xxx",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

I have been searching a lot and found that I might need to use a for loop together with the  `document.getElementsByClassName("cut_oak_tree");` 
but I can't really get that to work. If I have figured my problem correctly, everything should be good if I could just determine which of the tree images in the div should be removed when it's pressed. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Html sample:

```
<div id "thanks">
        <img class="cut_oak_tree" src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(), myFunction()">
        <img class="cut_oak_tree" src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(), myFunction()">
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML?

Comment: In sharp contrast to getElementById, which returns only a SINGLE element and thus needs no index behind itself, getElementsByClassName gets MULTIPLE elements (as symbolized by the "s" behind Element. Thus, it needs a [i] index behind itself. Like: getElementsByClassName("my_class")[0]

Comment: @StefanGruenwald I have tried adding what you just said, the problem is that both of the trees are now disapearing instead of just the one you clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cut_oak_tree")[0];
```

If you want to apply changes to more than one elements with classname `cut_oak_tree` then you will have to use *for loop*

```
var getClass = document.getElementsByClassName("cut_oak_tree");
for(i=0;i<getClass.length;i++)
{
    getClass[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

---

Using your earlier HTML with slight modifications you can do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cut_oak_tree">
    <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction()" />
    <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction()" />
</div>
```

Hence change your **JS** function to :

```
function loadXMLDoc(h)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var getEle = document.getElementsByClassName('cut_oak_tree')[0];
        getEle.innerHTML = getEle.innerHTML.replace(h,xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.pbpixels.com/x/post.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLL2m/)

---

Response to comment:

Inorder to uniquely identify clicked `<img>`s with same images just make minor change to the one of the img srcs from the two.Example give space within src src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png ".Note the space after .png which will make the difference between the two

Comment: This almost worked, except that both trees disapear when only one of the trees are clicked. Besides that, it works. Thanks

Comment: @Zword Out of curiosity, does the "this" pointer works in JavaScript onclick handlers?

Comment: Uhm this is still making both of my trees disapear even though only one of them are clicked. I will update my code in 2 min

Comment: @Zword I have updated the code in my post above, however I have the same problem with both my trees disapearing when only one of the trees are clicked

Comment: @Xavier_Ex yes "this" will work for onclick javascript

Comment: @user3287771 i will soon post a fiddle

Comment: @Zword ooo, that almost did it, really nice. The problem now is that one of the trees disapears even if you press the other tree. So I can press on the left tree, and then the right one will disapear.

Comment: @user3287771 thats because both img htmls are same

Comment: @Zword Ah yeah I see, it works with two different images. Would it be hard to get it working even though the two pictures are the same?

Comment: @Zword then why not use "this" to target the one being clicked?

Comment: @Zword Thanks a lot for everything. It works perfectly now as I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the most straightforward way to do it would be to pass the clicked element into the `loadXMLDoc()` as a parameter, and then get the parent of that element.  Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="cut_oak_tree">
    <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this), myFunction()">
    <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this), myFunction()">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function loadXMLDoc(clickedElement) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            clickedElement.parentNode.innerHTML = xmlhttpinnerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //ask for this.
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","xxx",true); //the xxx's represent my website
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**NOTE:** *I'm not 100% sure that I have the logic right, since you changed your original post, while I was typing up my answer.  :)*

**UPDATE #2:** I found the original code in the edit history . . . my code should be correct now.

Comment: I'm sorry that I changed the post while you were using it, I didn't really think about that. I appreciate your answer and I'll take a look at it, thanks a lot :)!

Comment: No worries . . . hope you get your answer.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Well I have another little question to think about. If I rather want to change the tree image to another image rather than just making it disapear. Would you then have any idea of how and where to implement it? :)

Comment: Looking at it, it looks like my HTML may be wrong now too . . . it was also supposed to be based on your original post, but it looks like I updated the revised HTML.   LOL

Comment: As for your second question, I'd recommend a second question on the site . . . otherwise, these questions start to get lengthy and off of the original topic.   :)

Comment: Alright thanks, I was just wondering if it was an easy implementation :)

Comment: Quick answer:  If you are passing in `this` (i.e., the `img` element that was clicked), it would be very easy to update the `src` parameter of it.

Comment: Heads up . . . I found your original code in the edit history . . . my code should be good now.

Comment: @talemyn your code targets parent element of the img clicked.So it will replace both http://jsfiddle.net/LDLU6/

Comment: With jQuery i would love to use $(this) for answering a solution for what OP asked .But this is pure javascript and "this" of javascript doesnt work exactly like we use it in jQuery.

Comment: @Zword - Yeah, I think what I was trying to solve changed, during all of the edits.   LOL   In the end, though, passing `this` into the function is going to give a much more detailed level of control, because you will know exactly what element was clicked and can work from there.

Comment: Yeah, @Zword, that's sort of why I was going that route . . . `$(this)` is so handy . . . just takes a little more "effort" to replicate it in pure JS.