# Using Javascript replace with getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, html

I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607869/using-javascript-replace-on-a-td-element) a few days ago which worked great and I thank those who helped but for reasons beyond my control I have to classes instead of id's as per my original post.

Basically what I am trying to do is remove the word "Other" from a string (The content is added dynamically through a form).

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom').innerHTML;
var text = str.replace("Other", " ");
document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom').innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.gv-field-4-custom {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-4-custom">Complex interventions, Evidence Synthesis (randomised trials), Studies within a Trial (SWAT), Trial Conduct, Trial Design, Other Core Outcome Sets (COS)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any advise as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript "getElementsByClassName" not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711417/javascript-getelementsbyclassname-not-working) and literally hundreds of others

Comment: @Robert O'Halloran use my answer. It will work. Just let me know if you have any trouble with that...

Comment: Thanks you all for your replies. After readign through the examples I now have a better idea of how to use this. Sorry it might have been a duplicated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is, that `getElementsByClassName` returns a set of elements, which in this particular case just contains a single element. If you just have a single element with this `className`, or just want to change one single element, you can go like this:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0];
var str = element.innerHTML;
var text = str.replace("Other", " ");
element.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.gv-field-4-custom {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-4-custom">Complex interventions, Evidence Synthesis (randomised trials), Studies within a Trial (SWAT), Trial Conduct, Trial Design, Other Core Outcome Sets (COS)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have more elements that need a treatment, go like this:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
  var text = str.replace("Other", " ");
  elements[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.gv-field-4-custom {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gv-field-4-custom">Complex interventions, Evidence Synthesis (randomised trials), Studies within a Trial (SWAT), Trial Conduct, Trial Design, Other Core Outcome Sets (COS)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var str = document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0];
  var oldText = str.innerHTML
  var text = oldText.replace("Other", " ");
  str.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Hi Nisar, your solution would seem to affect only the first element [0] in a possibility of many elements with this class. How do you apply your solution to all elements not just [0]? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom') 
will returns an array.You cannot directly get the innerHtml.

use    document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0].innerHtml to get the value.Use the below code

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0].innerHTML;
var text = str.replace("Other", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the `s` in getElementsByClassName. It means you need to loop over these.

You can use either the code

```
var className= document.getElementsByClassName("gv-field-4-custom");
for(i=0;i<className.length;i++)
{
    className[i].innerHTML = "text";
}
```

like @saina suggested, or use `document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0]` like @Imran suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')[0]
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gv-field-4-custom')
```